# How to get PHAsset of image after saving it to photos libary?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

How do I get the PHAsset of the image after I have saved it, so I can save the local identifier of the asset to my storage solution and use the image later?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I have never had to do this, but I would imagine there is a PhotoKit method that allows retrieving info for the **most recent image saved** to the default photo album.

That should work as long as no one takes screenshots right after the image is saved.  Lol.